# Wordpress: First blog entry disappears (only in Firefox!)

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

I have a weird problem with a Wordpress blog. It works fine in all browsers, except for Firefox. The first blog entry does not show! If I view the source code in Firefox, the blog entry is there, is just not visible when viewing it normally.

I have tried to look for a solution, but can't find any. Is there any big differences regarding how Firefox process CSS or anything that I should think about?

The site is here: http://lissis.vixen.no/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves it, but you have to test how this works out in other browsers:

In style.css on line 1120 (.entry-wrap), remove overflow: hidden
In style.css on line 1175 (.entry-content header), remove overflow: auto